# Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

A few weeks ago I stupidly moved my var folder into my root folder and my whole system broke. I managed to get things fixed somewhat, but my sites are not working because apache2 doesn't run/ doesn't exist
when i run the command

```
sudo service apache2
```

i get:

```
Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.
```

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

I literally have no clue how to fix this. I replaced /etc/apt/sources.list with the default configuration.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` yet?  You might not have up-to-date data, esp. if you purged your `/var` folder by accident.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes. i get this error for a few items (28: No space left on device)

Comment: No space on device means your disk is full.  You need to delete some files so commands can work (`sudo apt update` downloads new software repository lists which are saved locally - your system has no space to store them so it can't work). You need to create disk space first.